# Disabling LostFocus behaviour when editing a cell in Silverlight 2 DataGrid

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, event-handling, focus

I have a custom `CellEditingTemplate` that has a textbox and a calendar control inside a grid. I've made the textbox receive the focus when the user edits the cell by pressing `F2` on the keyboard. Unfortunately Silverlight's data grid hooks up to the Grid's `LostFocus` event so when the user clicks on the date picker control, the `LostFocus` event fires and the cell exits edit mode. Anyone got any ideas on how to stop this from happening? (If only Silverlight had a `.Handled` property on `RoutedEventArgs`.)

**Sample XAML:**

```
<data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
      <TextBox Loaded="FocusTextBox"
         Text="{Binding Path=ETD, Mode=TwoWay}" />
      <controls:DatePicker
         x:Name="datePicker"
         SelectedDate="{Binding Path=ETD, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeConverter}}"
         Margin="2"
         Width="22"
         HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the focus causing it? UIElements have a .CaptureMouse() event on them, you could try setting that on the calendar while it's in edit mode perhaps? I'm not sure this will work, just a suggestion.

Comment: I have investigated the DataGrid's code using Reflector, essentially when a Cell enters edit mode, the data grid subscribes to the GotFocus event of the root content element that is created. Then when GotFocus is fired, the LostFocus is subscribed to. There seems to be no way to prevent this.